# Maintain N latest points in Postgres

Tags: postgresql

My purpose is to have N latest points in Postgres in one row. When a new point is added, remove the oldest point.

For example say I have N+1 points. 1 userid and N integers.
Now when a new integer comes for a user, I want to remove the oldest entry and add the new entry. Obviously the issue is performance here. Since I am adding only one new integer, I want some way to do it fast.

I tried one very naive way by keeping two columns

```
userid, json
```

where `json` was list of all integers. I would remove the first entry and append new entry and dump json in postgres. Undoubtedly it is not performing well.

Please suggest some good way to do it. Does Postgres has some min heap type of data structure which does it in much better than linear complexity?

Comment: What about an array?  Can you show your DDL and the colum in question?

Comment: "*Does Postgres has some min heap type of data structure*" - yes, it's called a table

Comment: If you want to store your points in one row, then linear complexity is the best you can do; Postgres uses [row versioning](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiversion_concurrency_control), so any change to the data structure means the whole thing needs to be be copied. To avoid this, you would need to store your list as entries in a separate table, but whether this performs better in practice depends very much on your value of N.

Comment: N is around 1500 and I might need to update thousands of such rows at a time.

Comment: With 1500 integers, not only would you be copying the whole structure around, but you'd be over the 2kB [TOAST](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/storage-toast.html) threshold, meaning that you're also paying for compression and/or out-of-line storage lookups with every access. Sounds to me like you'd be much better off with a table.

Comment: What about integer array in postgres? Is it not maintained in optimized way where integer can be appended without much cost?